# I want to show the details of a flatlist item inside a pop up, how can I do it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

> HomesScreen.js
> This is where I am rendering the flat list elements

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Button, Image, Modal, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {FontAwesome} from "@expo/vector-icons"
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import TopHeading from './home_components/TopHeading';
import TopSlider from './home_components/TopSlider';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Cupons from './home_components/Cupons';
import { useState } from 'react';
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { FastField } from 'formik';




export default function HomeScreen  () {

const [dataa= [], setData] = useState();

  fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=Pakistan&from=2022-06-26&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=******************')
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then((data => {
  setData(data.articles)
 }))

 const common = [
    {
        name: "Test-1",
        url: require("../assets/image.jpg")
    },
    {
        name: "Test-2",
        url: require("../assets/image.jpg")
    },
    {
        name: "Test-3",
        url: require("../assets/image.jpg")
    },
    {
        name: "Test-4",
        url: require("../assets/image.jpg")
    },
    {
        name: "Test-5",
        url: require("../assets/image.jpg")
    },
    

  ]


  const cupon= [
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Dabdob",
      desc: "Offer: 10%",
    },
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Noon",
      desc: "Offer: cashback 10%",
    },
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Deraah",
      desc: "Offer: Free Shipping",
    },
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Al-Qassim Health Water",
      desc: "Offer: 11%",
    },
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Danube",
      desc: "( SR 10 (3 times use",
    },
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Styli Shop",
      desc: "Offer: 10%",
    },
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Naseem",
      desc: "Offer: 15%-10%",
    },
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Shgardi",
      desc: "Offer: 25%",
    },
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Click Toys",
      desc: "Offer: 10%",
    },
    {
      url: require("../assets/image2.jpg"),
      head: "Nanaa",
      desc: "Offer: 50% cash back",
    },
  ]
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false)

  const handleModal = () => setIsModalVisible(() => !isModalVisible);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
    <View style={styles.header}>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
            <Image  style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/mainLogo.png")} />
            <View style={styles.searchbarContainer}>
                <FontAwesome 
                color={"orange"} 
                style={{marginTop:12, paddingLeft:5}} 
                size={15} 
                name='search' />
                <TextInput 
                style={styles.searchBar} 
                placeholder='Search..'/>
                </View>
            </View>
            </View>
        <View style={{alignSelf: "stretch", borderColor: "red", height:160, justifyContent:"space-between", alignItems: "center",marginHorizontal:20 }}>
        <TopHeading />
        <FlatList 
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces
        data={common} 
        renderItem = {({item, index})=>{
            return <TopSlider heading= {item.name}  img={item.url} index={index} />
        }
        }
        horizontal  />

        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: 95,marginHorizontal: 0}}>
           
        <FlatList 
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={dataa} 
        renderItem = {({item})=>{
            return  <Cupons imgUrl={item.urlToImage} name={item.author} title={item.title} desc={item.description} content={item.content}  />
        }
        }
        />
        
        </View>
        
    <StatusBar style={'auto'} />
    
      </View>
      
      );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItems: "center"

  },
  header:{
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 130,
    backgroundColor: "rgb(32, 68, 124)",
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    alignItems: 'center', 
    
  },
  logo:{
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    tintColor: "white",
    
  },
  innerContainer:{
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: 70,
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 50,
  },

  searchbarContainer:{
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    width: 300,
    height: 40,
  },
  searchBar:{
    paddingLeft: 5,
    width: 280,
  }
  


});
```

> Cupons.js
> When an element of this screen is pressed then the pop up should open with that element's detail
> import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
> import { Button, Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
> import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
> import { Modal } from 'react-native-paper';
> import { useState } from 'react';
> import CuponDetails from '../CuponDetail';

```
export default function Cupons({imgUrl, name, desc, title, content}) {
  

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false)

  const handleModal = () => setIsModalVisible(() => !isModalVisible);
 
  
  return (

    <View >
      
     <TouchableOpacity onPress= {()=>{ navigation.navigate("CuponDetails", {
        ImgUrl : imgUrl,
        Name : name,
        Desc : desc,
        Title: title,
        Content: content,
      }) 
      console.log("Cupon", imgUrl)
    }}
    >
      
    
    <View style= {styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
        <View stytle= {styles.imageContainer}><Image resizeMode='cover' style={styles.image} source={{uri: `${imgUrl}`}}/></View>
        <View style={styles.textContainer}><Text style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 16}} >{name}</Text><Text style={{fontSize:16, color: "grey", overflow: "hidden", padding:5}}>{title}</Text></View>
        </View>
        <Text style={{alignSelf: "center",  fontSize:20, fontWeight: "bold"}}>Description</Text>
        <Text 
        style={{marginHorizontal:10,  
        marginVertical:10, 
        height: "auto", 
        overflow: "scroll",
        fontSize: 20,
        padding:5, 
        borderBottomWidth:0, 
        borderTopWidth:0,
        fontSize:14,
        color: "grey",
        alignItems:"center", 
        justifyContent: "center" }}>{desc}</Text>
        
    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
     
    </View>
    
    
      
  
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "rgb(250,250,250)",
    height: "auto",
    margin: 10,
    width: 350,
    borderRadius: 10,
    elevation: 5,
    shadowColor: "rgb(100,100,255,)",
    position: "relative",
    overflow: "hidden",
    justifyContent: "center",
    
    


    

  },
  topContainer:{
    margin: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
    justifyContent: "center",

  },
  imageContainer:{
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: 60,
    width:80,
    elevation: 10,
    shadowColor: "rgb(100,100,255,)",
    marginBottom: 10,

  },
  image:{
    height:70,
    width: 80,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
    
  },
  textContainer:{
    margin: 5,
    height:"auto",
    width:300,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
  
});
```

> CuponsDetails.js
> I want to show this screen in pop-up

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Button, Image, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Modal } from 
'react-native';
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {FontAwesome} from "@expo/vector-icons"
import { useState } from 'react';


export default function CuponDetails({route,navigation}) {
  
  const {ImgUrl} = route.params;
  const {Name} = route.params;
  const {Desc} = route.params;
  const {Title} = route.params;
  const {Content} = route.params;
  var TAG = "CouponDetail";
    console.log(TAG,ImgUrl)

  return (
    <ScrollView  style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}>
        
    <View style= {styles.container}> 
    <View style = {styles.imageContainer}><Image style={{width:250, height: 200,}} resizeMode='cover' source={{uri: `${ImgUrl}`}} /></View>
    <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
        <Text style={{
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: 18
        }}>{Name}</Text>
        
        <Text style={{
            fontWeight: "normal",
            fontSize: 14,
        }}>{Title}</Text>

    </View>
    <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
        <Text style={{
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: 18
        }}>Description</Text>
        
        <Text style={{
            fontWeight: "normal",
            fontSize: 14,
        }}>{Desc}</Text>

    </View>

    <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
        <Text style={{
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: 18
        }}>Content</Text>
        
        <Text style={{
            fontWeight: "normal",
            fontSize: 14,
        }}>{Content}</Text>

    </View>
    </View>
    
    </ScrollView>   
    
  
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    overflow: "scroll",

  },
  imageContainer:{
    height: 200,
    width: 250,
    marginTop: 50,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: "hidden",
    elevation: 2,
    shadowColor: "rgb(100,100,255,)",

  },
  headingContainer:{
    width: 350,
    marginVertical: 10,
    height: "auto",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 15,
    padding: 8,
    elevation: 2,
    shadowColor: "rgb(100,100,255,)",
    backgroundColor: "white"

  }
})
```

> What I wanna do.
> I am rendering Cupon.js in HomeScreen.js with flat list and I want to open a pop-up when the rendered cupon element is pressed with its detail like CuponDetails.js but the pop-up should have HomeScreen in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use conditional rendering..
means declare a variable in  `HomeScreen.js` and after the cupon element is pressed change its value to true and set the condition as

`showCupon ? <Cupon withProperties={} /> : null`

here by default value of showCupon is false after pressing the element call setShowCupon (use useState hook ) and give the style accordingly..

Comment: or you can use reactBootstrap's 'modal Component' if you are familiar with reactBootstrap.